# Запуск процесса через кнопку в datagridview C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

Есть колонка с данными в datagridview

1. id
2. button start
3. key
4. data

Нужно, что бы по нажатию на кнопку "start" запускался процесс с данными из колонки, в которой была нажата кнопка. Как это сделать ?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй DataGrid.SelectedItem

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).